# Rehashing separate chaining in C++, Vector of linked list of pairs

Tags: c++11, vector, hash, chaining, std-pair

I am trying to make a function that rehashes a hash table which is a vector of linked lists or pairs. I have right now:

```
//Resizes the hash to contain at least n buckets
void rehash(int n) {

    list<pair<K,V>> temp = table;
    clear();
    buckets = findNextPrime(n);
    
    table.resize(buckets);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
        list<pair<K,V> lst = temp[i];
        for (pair<K,V> item : lst) {
            this -> insert(item);
        }
    }
    temp.clear();

}
```

I am getting a couple errors and I am very new to working with pairs, so I don't understand quite where I'm going wrong. These are the errors I'm getting:

```
ChainingHash.h:247:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  247 |       list<pair<K,V> lst = temp[i];
      |                                  ^
ChainingHash.h:247:34: error: template argument 2 is invalid
ChainingHash.h:248:29: error: ‘lst’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘lstat’?
  248 |       for (pair<K,V> item : lst) {
ChainingHash.h:240:29: error: conversion from ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >’ to non-scalar type ‘std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >’ requested
  240 |      list<pair<K,V>> temp = table;
```

Comment: `list<pair<K,V> lst = temp[i];` If nothing else, there are more opening angle brackets here than closing ones.

Comment: If `list` here is `std::list`, then it doesn't provide `operator[]`. So `temp[i]` won't compile.